# Solve issue of upgrading to php 7.2 in laravel 5.4 application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I have Upgraded my **laravel** application php version to **php 7.2** this week and from then I am facing big problems in my **laravel** application. before upgrading **php to 7.2** every thing worked pefectly.

the main issue is about **count()** and **array_merge()** functions which is throwing this error:

for `array_merge()` function the code is as below:

```
$array = array_merge(
                $model->toSearchableArray(), $model->scoutMetadata()
            );

            if (empty($array)) {
                return;
            }
```

> ErrorException · array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array.

and I am facing `count()` error for example at this code when the model returns no records and returns null:

```
count(TutorialReview::where('TutorialID', 5)->where('UserID', 6)->get())
```

`count()`: Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable.

my laravel version is **5.4**

now my question is how can I solve the issues, and does upgrading to **laravel 5.5** solve any of the issues?

Comment: using @ for ignore the warning i think.

Answer (score 5):

In **PHP 7.2** changed `count()` behavior in the following RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/counting_non_countables

But you can get count using `->count()` in **laravel**, here is an example of it:

```
$count = TutorialReview::where('TutorialID', 5)->where('UserID', 6)->get()->count();
```

This way you can get total records count.

Comment: thanks, it seems this is the solution for the count issue. my problem was because each time after get() function I used ->first() and that in count() function would gives the error.

Comment: @atiehmokhtary, if this is solution for your question, you can accept as answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Just add `@` before `count`. I.E.

```
@count(object or array);
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly! but i need a further explanation why i need to add the @ symbol.

Comment: @ad3bay0 the @ symbol suppresses errors on a given function call

Comment: doesnt solve the underlying problem, just tells the error to keep quiet

Answer (score 2):

**To solve array_merge() issue** , try those steps:

1. sluggable.php config file at app/config with data

   `return ['source' => null, 'maxLength' => null, 'method' => null, 'separator' => '-', 'unique' => true, 'uniqueSuffix' => null, 'includeTrashed' => false, 'reserved' => null, 'onUpdate' => false, ];`
2. Execute the command, `php artisan config:cache`

**To solve count() issue** : [Try This](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22373)

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable.
```

Actually its not a error , its an expected behavior . Laravel 5.4 or 5.5 is not fully compatible with Php 7.2 .
Count() behaviour just change at PHP 7.2 
[Look at this](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/counting_non_countables)

Another way just use PHP 7.1 or below until compatibility issue fixed.

Comment: thanks for reply, I can not find sluggable.php file, would you please explain more about solve array_merge() issue?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$array = array_merge(
    collect($model->toSearchableArray())->toArray(), $model->scoutMetadata()
);
```

also when counting model instance do this by `->count()` instead of `count()`

Answer (score 0):

just add below code in web.php

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.2.0', '>=')) {
    // Ignores notices and reports all other kinds... and warnings
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
    // error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING); // Maybe this is enough
}
```